# scroll to a div after jquery form submit

Tags: jquery, forms, submit, scrollto, scrolltop

i already test all the ways to scroll to a **DIV ID** but don't work i know is something wrong but i don't know what, this is my jquery script

```
$("#sub").click( function() {

$("#myForm").validate({
      rules: {
        page: {
          required: true,
          url: true
        },
        link: {
          required: true,
          url: true
        }
      },
      submitHandler: function(form) {
        $.post( $("#myForm").attr("action"), $("#myForm :input").serializeArray(), 
        function(info){ 
            $("#result").html(info); 
        });

        clearInput();

        $("#myForm").submit( function() {
            return false;   
        });
                    }
    });
});

function clearInput() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#result").offset().top
    }, 2000);
}
```

I don't know if something is mixing the thing but the jquery don't scroll i test the `scrolltop()` function in a new php file and works fine but when i use it on this file don't.

**UPDATE:**

Thanks for your help netblognet i already got it, i make this:

```
$("#sub").click( function() {

    $("#myForm").validate({
          rules: {
            page: {
              required: true,
              url: true
            },
            link: {
              required: true,
              url: true
            }
          },
          submitHandler: function(form) {
            $.post( $("#myForm").attr("action"), $("#myForm :input").serializeArray(), 
            function(info){ 
                $("#result").html(info); 
                //$(this).animate(function(){
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $("#result").offset().top
                     }, 2000);
            //});
            });


            $("#myForm").submit( function() {
                return false;
            });
                        }
        });
});
```

I put the code on the same place that the income results :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to run your animation in the submit's callback. The callback is triggered when the initial function has run. (In this case the submit function.)

```
$("#myForm").submit( function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
         scrollTop: $("#result").offset().top
    }, 2000);
    return false;
});
```

If your form is loaded dynamically you have to attach a handler.

```
$('#myForm').on('submit', function() {
    $('html, body').animate({
         scrollTop: $("#result").offset().top
    }, 2000);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: i already test that and don't work :( i don't know if is because i'm using a external file, because if i use that in the <head> works fine, but if i use this from a .js file don't inclusive if is the only operation on the file

Comment: Have you tested if any function from your included .js-file works? May your file isn't included correctly. Habe you tried pressing F12 in browser and check the script/js console? Maybe you can see the errors over there...

Comment: all the other operations in the .js file works fine, that's the only line that have the issue, and the console don't show me any issue and again no matter if i clean all the .js file and i only put your example, the script continue without work

Comment: Ok, I edited my answer. Could you please try both approaches again?